# Can I use a USB as a hard drive for Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360

I'm trying to install Destiny the Taken King but it says I have to have an Xbox 360 hard drive.

I don't want to buy one and I need to know if I can format a USB flash drive or do something with a USB to make it act like a hard drive.

Comment: Why don't you have a hard drive?  They're basically standard for consoles now.

Comment: The taken king is a 20gb download, so unless you have a flash drive big enough...

Comment: Yeah but my Xbox when I bought it somehow didn't HAVE a hard drive

Answer (score 2):

You can use up to 2TB, (with OS version: 2.0.17349.0 or later, otherwise there's a 16GB limit) from a USB for expanding the memory of an Xbox 360 console, for profiles, game saves and downloadable content. Original Xbox games cannot be stored on a USB flash drive.

Note that the minimum size is 1GB and that 512MB of the device will be unusable as it will be reserved for System use.

To use USB storage, you'll either need the recommended preconfigurered Xbox 360 branded SanDisk USB flash drive, or you'll need to configure your own USB.

Your USB will need to be formatted to FAT32 if it is not already, this can be done on your computer. If your USB is larger than 32GB you may not be able to do this with the Windows formatter, there are [answers on Super User instructing how to do this](https://superuser.com/a/695376/449453).

Ensure you have at least the Spring 2010 update or later and then plug the USB into the xbox and go to `System Settings` then `Memory` and select your USB device. Select `Configure Now` to erase all existing data and configure the entire device.

Alternatively select `Customize` and move the slider to select how much of the storage space you want to configure for Xbox data storage and then click `Configure`.

Note that your USB will need to be rated above a recommended speed otherwise you may experience reduced game quality and performance.

Comment: Could I recommend reposting this on the original? The current accepted answer is pre-2TB update, and this is very helpful